# How to resolve Maven cfx build failure?

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, build-error

I'm pretty new to java and maven and I'm trying to build the apache cxf project. I get an error during the build and I don't have any clue what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody give me some input on what I need to change to run the build properly?

I have been running `mvn clean install` and got an build error I don't understand. You can find it here: https://pastebin.com/Vdvi4unU

My end goal is to run `mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=tgf -DappendOutput=true -DoutputFile=output.tgf` to get all the dependencies of a project.

The pom from apache cfx: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Could you add pom file itself?

Comment: I'm trying to just build the Apache CXF on it's own. I don't use it within my project. I added a link to the pom. In my opinion is should work out of the box, as it is a release version 3.0.0 I'm trying to build.

Comment: Is this under MacOS?  You need to set the JAVA_HOME variable correctly.

Comment: yes, MacOS. Thank you for the typ, I'll have a look at the JAVA_HOME variable.